# Display dynamically created hyperlinks in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I need to create an unspecified number of hyperlink objects within the controller and then display them within the view. I have no trouble dynamically creating the hyperlink objects within HomeController.cs, however I cannot get said hyperlink objects to be properly displayed in the view.

Here is the code which creates the hyperlinks, puts them in a list, and then adds that list to the ViewBag

```
            List<HyperLink> links = new List<HyperLink>();
            List<HyperLink> tempLink = new List<HyperLink>();
            string line = "";
            output = "";
            while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                output += "\n" + line;
                if (!line.Equals(""))
                {
                    tempLink = GetLineNumbers(line, destpath);
                    if (tempLink.Count > 0)
                    {
                        links.AddRange(tempLink); // HYPERLINKS ADDED TO LIST HERE
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
            ViewBag.links = links; // LIST OF HYPERLINKS ADDED TO VIEWBAG HERE
```

Here is the code within my view:

```
<h2> RESULTS </h2>
<article>
    <pre>
        @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.links.Count; i++)
        {
            @ViewBag.links[i] //HYPERLINKS SUPPOSED TO BE DISPLAYED HERE
        }
    </pre>
</article>
```

Currently what gets displayed by the view is this:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink

Of course, I'd like to have those nice, blue, underlined hyperlinks but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm quite the ASP.NET noob and I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink` is WebForms control. Why are you using that in a MVC app? I assume you want a property of `HyperLink` like `@ViewBag.links[i].NavigateUrl` but that will just return the url as a string, not an `<a>` tag.

Comment: I'd like to display @ViewBag.links[i].Text but as you say, this will only return a simple string.

I'm using System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink because it just seemed like an easy way to create hyperlinks. Is there a better Class I could be using?

Comment: Then build the `<a>` tag in the loop `<a href="@ViewBag.links[i].NavigateUrl ....` But why are you doing this using a webForms control?

Comment: I didn't explain very well. I'd like to display a normal hyperlink with the string in ViewBag.links[i].Text being displayed (as opposed to an image or something else). 

Using a webForms control as opposed to what?

Comment: I cant imagine why or what your trying to do here. Whats the point of using a WebForms control. Just create a view model with `string url` and `string displayText`, populate a collection and in the loop `<a href="@ViewBag.links[i].Url">@ViewBag.links[i].DisplayText</a>` (I'm assuming this must be a collection of external links in a text file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly answering your question but this would be a more manageable solution for you:

Why not construct a class of something like this:

```
 public class DynamicHyperLink
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string Link { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you would apply the text you wanted to display to the text property and the link to the Link property

Once you have done this then in the Controller you pass this as a model to your view like this:

```
 public ActionResult DynamicLinks()
        {
            List<DynamicHyperLink> model = new List<DynamicHyperLink>()
            {
                new DynamicHyperLink(){
                    Text = "Some Text Here", 
                    Link = "http://www.somelink.com"
                }, 
                 new DynamicHyperLink(){
                    Text = "Some Other Text ", 
                    Link = "http://www.someotherlink.com"
                }
            };

            return View(model); 

        }
```

Obviously you would want to use your function to build this up out of the controller but gives you an idea and then in the view:

```
@model List<DynamicHyperLink>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DynamicLinks";
}

<h2>DynamicLinks</h2>




@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <a href="@item.Link">@item.Text</a>
        </div>

    }
}
```

This would then generate the links for you and then if you wanted to add custom styling the links you could add this as an additional property.

Hope this helps and if you need any more info let me know.

Comment: Ah thank you! And you're right, the use of the hyperlink class isn't necessary. My View now displays the hyperlinks properly thanks to the View code you've put up, but I'll put in the other changes you've suggested for readability sake. You've been a major help, thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

How I got around this issue was by using the @html.raw(Viewbag.Test). Inside my controller I just created a viewbag. Easy work around if you only have a few hyperlinks

```
    ViewBag.Message = "<a href="+Website+">Website Text</a>";
```